# SOLR how can I trigger deletion using $deleteDocById with DIH

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I need to delete some documents during full-import with `dataimporter.request.clean == false`.  This limits the options open to me and it seems that using `$deleteDocById` would be my best option.  However I cannot find a good example of how to achieve this.

I am using sometihing along the lines of:

```
<document>
    <entity query="select id, text
        IF(yadda.dateyyy <= NOW(),yadda.id,NULL) AS $deleteDocById,
        IF(yadda.dateyyy <= NOW(),yadda.id,NULL) AS $skipDoc,
        from yadda">
    </entity>
 </document>
```

the GET parameters `?command=full-import&clean=false` seems to trigger correctly with the final report including `Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 72 documents. Deleted 4 documents.` however when query the supposedly deleted documents are still in the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$skipDoc` needed to be set to the string value `"true"` in order for this to work.

```
<document>
    <entity query="select id, text
        IF(yadda.dateyyy <= NOW(),yadda.id,NULL) AS $deleteDocById,
        IF(yadda.dateyyy <= NOW(),"true",NULL) AS $skipDoc,
        from yadda">
    </entity>
 </document>
```